# Where does this number come from and how can i get this to work?

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++! and i was wondering how i get 1984400537 when adding, also how can i get the the program to accept a + - * or / and use them? Thanks!
~mccallbush ;)
P.S if you need anymore info please let me know!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char repeat = 'y';
    string x;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int result;

    cout << "Please select one of the following: + - * /" << "\n";
    cin >> x;

    while(repeat == 'y')
    {
        if(x == "+")
        {
            result = num1 + num2;
            cout << "Please enter your first number: " << "\n";
            cin >> num1;
            cout << "Please enter your second number: " << "\n";
            cin >> num2;
            cout << "Answer is: " << result << "\n";
        }
        else if(x == "-")
        {
            result = num1 - num2;
            cout << "Please enter your first number: " << "\n";
            cin >> num1;
            cout << "Please enter your second number: " << "\n";
            cin >> num2;
            cout << "Answer is: " << result << "\n";
        }
        else if(x == "*")
        {
            result = num1 * num2;
            cout << "Please enter your first number: " << "\n";
            cin >> num1;
            cout << "Please enter your second number: " << "\n";
            cin >> num2;
            cout << "Answer is: " << result << "\n";
        }
        else if(x == "/")
        {
            result = num1 / num2;
            cout << "Please enter your first number: " << "\n";
            cin >> num1;
            cout << "Please enter your second number: " << "\n";
            cin >> num2;
            cout << "Answer is: " << result << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You did not enter a correct symbol please try again. \n";
        }
        cout << "Do you want to repeat?(y/n): ";
        cin >> repeat;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a result of a rather sophisticated process known as a "random number generator", which you use whenever you fail to initialize your variables.

Comment: You are adding two numbers *before* you have asked the user to enter them. Which means, you are adding two uninitialized variables containing random garbage.

Comment: Put this statement: `result = num1 + num2;` after inputting your variables.

Comment: This is the sort of situation that a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) can help you get out of.

Comment: The code has a lot of problems in short.

Comment: Remember that in `c++` assignments happen in the exact line that you do the assignment. They are not a mathematical relationship that the computer will execute at a later time.

Comment: ok thanks eveyone :)

Comment: I've answered the question, @mccallbush, please try it out ad tell me whether it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of mistakes in your code:

**Firstly**, in the lines:

```
result = num1 + num2;
cout << "Please enter your first number: " << "\n";
cin >> num1;
cout << "Please enter your second number: " << "\n";
cin >> num2;
cout << "Answer is: " << result << "\n";
```

You are doing the calculation before you even *accept* the values; you ask for the numbers as input from the user after you have done the calculation. This problem is in all 4 if-statements. To fix this, change your code to:

```
cout << "Please enter your first number: " << "\n";
cin >> num1;
cout << "Please enter your second number: " << "\n";
cin >> num2;
result = num1 + num2; // After numbers are inputted, but before the sum is output
cout << "Answer is: " << result << "\n";
```

I'll leave it to you to fix the rest of the if-statements.

---

**Secondly**, you only ask the user once for the choice before you enter the while loop. After that, you move  infinitely through the loop **only** doing the operation ou chose before entering the loop, since the `x` variable's value is never modified inside the loop. Therefore, you can change your code to:

```
while(repeat == 'y')
{
    cin.clear(); // I'll explain this.
    cout << "Please select one of the following: + - * /" << "\n";
    cin >> x;

    // Do the rest of the while loop.
}
```

This way, you can modify the options while you are in the while loop. The `cin.clear()` was necessary, because input needs to be cleared; else, it will lead to an endless output. Try removing the statement and see for yourself. (see [Can you explain cin.ignore() and cin.clear() for C++? When is it appropriate to use these? How do they effect the next cin>>?](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-explain-cin-ignore-and-cin-clear-for-C++-When-is-it-appropriate-to-use-these-How-do-they-effect-the-next-cin) for more clarification).

This should sort the problem (I've tried and tested it). If something I mentioned is unclear, or if you need any more help, please inform me in the comments box.